# SSRS 2005 passing datetime parameter to Oracle

Tags: oracle, reporting-services

I have a SSRS 2005 report runs on a Oracle 9 database.

The report use this simple query to return a dataset

```
    SELECT order_number FROM apps.oe_order_headers_all  
    WHERE ordered_date >= to_date(:start_date,'DD-MON-YYYY') 
    AND ordered_date  < to_date(:end_date,'DD-MON-YYYY') +1
```

The parameters work fine if they are of type string in SSRS. E.g. 01-JAN-2014 for both start_date and end_date. But if changed to datetime the report returns nothing (if in string, the report returns many rows). I really want to use the date picker control of SSRS.

This is probably more of a SSRS thing than Oracle thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably a date conversion issue, but I'm surprised it isn't either erroring, or returning the same data - at least for the example date you gave.

In your previous question you were entering a string, so adding the `to_date()` made sense. But if you're binding it *as a date* then you do not want those.

This is fine:

```
to_date(<string>,'DD-MON-YYYY')
```

But this:

```
to_date(<date>,'DD-MON-YYYY')
```

is really doing:

```
to_date(to_char(<date>,<NLS_DATE_FORMAT>), 'DD-MON-YYYY')
```

If your `NLS_DATE_FORMAT happens to be the same as the fixed format you supplied, then this is kind of OK as it's just a redundant conversion to a string and back. But if they are different then you'll get errors or incorrect results.

For example, if my `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is `MM/DD/YYYY' then`to_date(sysdate, 'DD-MON-YYYY`) gets an`ORA-01843: not a valid month`error, because it's trying to interpret`28`as the month and`02` as the day.

So you just need to simplify it to:

```
SELECT order_number FROM apps.oe_order_headers_all  
WHERE ordered_date >= :start_date
AND ordered_date  < :end_date +1
```

Given the odd error you get from this, you could also try:

```
AND ordered_date < :end_date + interval '1' day
```

... but without understanding why the simpler `+1` is erroring I'm not confident that will help. It doesn't seem to be following the normal [datetime arithmetic rules](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF00208). This is another possibility but should not be necessary:

```
AND ordered_date < CAST(:end_date AS DATE) + 1
```

Comment: Hi, I got this ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER. But if I removed '+ 1' it works. Probably a pl sql thing now?

Comment: @thotwielder - that's an odd error, it should be fine if the bind is actually a date. Not sure if that's something unusual about how the date is being passed by SSRS, an OCI thing (using an internal raw format), or... what. I'm not abel to experiment with that unfortunately.

Comment: @AlexPoole the _arithmetic expression_ is evaluated first.. when `+ 1` is seen, the other operand is too expected as NUMBER (since the priority is more over NUMBER than as a date.. a `to_date()` should have solved that).. Where-as in Relational check with a `DATE` datatype.. it is implicitly cast as `DATE`!! Just my guess..

Comment: @OracleUser - if that was the case wouldn't `select * from dual where sysdate < sysdate + 1` also fail? The error suggests it's evaluating `:end_date +1` as a number; like `select * from dual where sysdate < 3` which throws ORA-00932 too. But that doesn't make any sense either.

Comment: Nope, i meant with expressions over bind variables.( Date as Date itself). I never tried that!!

Comment: @AlexPoole AND ordered_date < CAST(:end_date AS DATE) + 1 works. Much appreciated.